# Python standard output and subprocesses

Tags: python, unix

I've got two files:

run.py

```
import subprocess
import time

while True:
  time.sleep(1)
  print 'hello'
  proc = subprocess.call(['./writer.sh'])
```

writer.sh (chmod 777'd)

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'write something here'
```

and I'm confused by the following outputs:

```
$ python run.py
hello
write something here
hello
write something here
hello
write something here
....

$ python run.py | tee out.log
write something here
write something here
(hello disappears)

....

$ python run.py > out.log
# Nothing, but out.log has the following:
write something here
write something here
write something here
write something here
hello
hello
hello
hello
... # and the two basically "expand" the longer I run this (instead of appending)
```

What is happening, and how can I get everything to output like the first command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of your main script is buffered. Call `sys.stdout.flush()` right before running the subprocess.

Comment: Ah, and both tee and redirecting to a file make the buffer not line-by-line, whereas just running to a tty flushes on every line. Thanks!